# WordPress plugin - Store shipping address in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, user-data

I'm trying to add shipping address to the current customer, but I doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    =>   $email,
    'user_email'    =>   $email,
    'user_pass'     =>   $password,
    'first_name'    =>   $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>   $last_name
);
$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata ); // User successfully inserted
$customer             = new WC_Customer();
$customer->set_shipping_city("Bangalore"); //Doesn't work
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->customer->set_shipping_city("Bangalore"); //Doesn't work
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );` doesn't insert any data, but just store it into `$user` variable and after in your code you don't use it anymore.
Then also  `set_shipping_city();` is a **session** data function and you need to use an existing customer or cart session (WC_cart).

So I have changed your code a little bit:

```
$userdata = array (
    'user_login'    =>  $email,
    'user_email'    =>  $email,
    'user_pass'     =>  $password,
    'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>  $last_name
) ;
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

// Here you insert your user data with a 'customer' user role
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'customer') ) ;

//Once customer user is inserted/created, you can retrieve his ID
global $current_user;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
// or use instead:  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Checking if user Id exist
if( !empty( $user_id ) ) {

    // You will need also to add this billing meta data
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $first_name );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $last_name );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $email );
    // optionally shipping meta data, that could be different
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $first_name );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $last_name );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_email', $email );

    // Now you can insert the required billing and shipping city
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', 'Bangalore' );
    // optionally shipping_city can be different…
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', 'Bangalore' );

} else {
    // echo 'User Id doesn't exist';
}
```

Then you can use [**`update_user_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/) function to insert any address data with **`keys`**:

```css
billing_first_name
billing_last_name
billing_company
billing_email
billing_phone
billing_address_1
billing_address_2
billing_country
billing_state
billing_postcode

shipping_first_name
shipping_last_name
shipping_company
shipping_email
shipping_phone
shipping_address_1
shipping_address_2
shipping_country
shipping_state
shipping_postcode
```

Reference:

- [WordPress Development StackExchange - wp_insert_user role not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224091/wp-insert-user-role-not-working/224093#224093)
- [WordPress function update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)
- [WordPress function wp_insert_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)
- [WordPress function wp_update_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/)
- [WordPress function wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)
- [WordPress function get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

wp_update_user( $userdata )

where $userdata are the list of fields.

Using wp_update_user you can update the field